# Get metadata from default ringtone

Tags: android

I have the URI for a specific sound file, the default ringtone `contents://settings/system/ringtone`. How I can get the title of and the other details of that song?

Comment: Nice edit, @Craigy! user1078570, you should learn from Craigy's example... If he hadn't edited to clarify, this question would have been closed as quickly as your other questions.

Comment: This question should be reopened now the edit is clear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the default ringtone metadata is a bit more complicated than you assume.

A good place to start is the [`RingtoneManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) class. It provides methods for getting the default [`Ringtone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html), from four areas:

```
int    TYPE_ALARM           Type that refers to sounds that are used for the alarm.
int    TYPE_ALL             All types of sounds.
int    TYPE_NOTIFICATION    Type that refers to sounds that are used for notifications.
int    TYPE_RINGTONE        Type that refers to sounds that are used for the phone ringer.
```

Using this class it is straightforward to get the default ringtone's title:

```
Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager
        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
String title = ringtone.getTitle(this);
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to get other data about ringtones.